# What is the best practice to write the rules of Firebase in a situation like this?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-authentication, authorization

## Initial approach/problem

The user will be able to write to his own **user** node. Then the user has to be able to write as many **buildings** he/she wants and as many **depts** as he/she wants (there are also **rooms** but I will leave that aside for now for clarity's sake). The user should be able to read (and write) his own user node, buildings and departments but not the other users' node, buildings and departments.

Basically:

User > user's Building > building's Department (TOTAL read and write permissions)

User > Another User's Stuff (NO Permissions at all)

Here is the database strucure:

```
{
  "buildings" : {
    "-L9Bc9aazn3mNiW1elJk" : {
      "address" : "",
      "comments" : "",
      "hasDepts" : {
        "-L9FwBmYEnkZQzdFJ4lU" : true
      },
      "name" : "J house",
      "ownerID" : "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3"
    }
  },
  "depts" : {
    "-L9FwBmYEnkZQzdFJ4lU" : {
      "comments" : "",
      "inBuilding" : "-L9Bc9aazn3mNiW1elJk",
      "name" : "Dep 1"
    },
  },
  "users" : {
    "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3" : {
      "isAdmin" : {
        "-L9Bc9aazn3mNiW1elJk" : true,
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Initial approach

Each **users** node has a child node **isAdmin** that contains all push keys of the **buildings** this user has created. Using the same logic, the **buildings**' node contains a **hasDepts** node with all the push keys from the **depts** that the user has created in that building.

If you can help I would really appreciate. Anybody out there?

I am using vue.js to write to firebase like this:

```
addBuilding: function () {
  let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  let buildingKey = buildingsRef.push().key;
  this.newBuilding.ownerID = userId;
  buildingsRef.child(buildingKey).set(this.newBuilding);
  usersRef.child(userId).child('isAdmin').child(buildingKey).set(true);
}
```

### Closest solution so far / by @André Kool (partially using the initial approach)

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  },
}, 
"buildings": {
    "$pushKey" : {
        ".read": "root.child('buildings').child($pushKey).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildings').child($pushKey).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid" 
  }
},
"depts": {
  "$pushKey": {
    ".read": "root.child('buildings').child(root.child('depts').child($pushKey).child('inBuilding').val()).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "root.child('buildings').child(root.child('depts').child($pushKey).child('inBuilding').val()).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid" 

  }
},
```

}

With @André Kool's attempt the simulator allows it to read/write to the **buildings/$pushKey** node. However while it shows the node on the frontend as soon as it it is created, when we refresh the browser or add a new building the node disappears from the frontend (remains on the database). Firebase it's also not allowing to write to the **depts** node. Any clues and possible solutions?

## UPDATE: another approach.

1) making sure both the **buildings** and **depts** nodes both have the **ownerId** child node, like this:

```
{
  "buildings" : {
    "-L9HIbKu5fIe8rfoePgi" : {
      "address" : "",
      "comments" : "",
      "hasDepts" : {
        "-L9HIdScisDItysCnMlm" : true
      },
      "name" : "building 1",
      "ownerID" : "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3"
    }
  },
  "depts" : {
    "-L9HIdScisDItysCnMlm" : {
      "comments" : "",
      "inBuilding" : "-L9HIbKu5fIe8rfoePgi",
      "name" : "dep 1",
      "ownerID" : "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3" : {
      "isAdmin" : {
        "-L9HIbKu5fIe8rfoePgi" : true
      },
      "name" : "João Alves Marrucho",
      "userEmail" : "joaomarrucho@hotmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

2) Use the **ownerId** to authorise read and writing on all buildings and depts:

```
"users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
    }, 
    "buildings": {
      "$id": {
        ".read": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid" , 
        ".write": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid"  
      }
    },
    "depts": {
      "$id": {
        ".read": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid" , 
        ".write": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid"  
      }
    },
  }
```

3) New problem with this approach!

With the rules above, using the simulator, it seems to me like firebase is not allowing the user to read/write to the **buildings** node but it's allowing to read/write to **buildings/$pushKey** node. Does firebase needs the user to be able read/write to both parent (**buildings**) and child node (**buildings/$pushKey**)?. And if so how can you prevent the user from deleting (.set) the whole **buildings** node?

I am asking this because if we add *".read": true, ".write": true* before the *$wildcards* it writes the intended database structure **while rendering the next rules on the cascade completely useless**... So that's no good, but at least it kind of hints where part of the solution may reside.

```
 "users": {
      ".read": true, <<<<<<
      ".write": true,   <<<<<<
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
    }, // but is should also be able to write to his own buildings
    "buildings": {
      ".read": true,   <<<<<<
      ".write": true,   <<<<<<
      "$id": {
        ".read": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid" , 
        ".write": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid"  
      }
    },
    "depts": {
      ".read": true,   <<<<<<
      ".write": true,   <<<<<<
      "$id": {
        ".read": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid" , 
        ".write": "data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid"  
      }
    },
  }
```

> (Other thoughts) 
>   I don't see why the user shouldn't be able to read/write to the **buildings** parent node (provided the rules prevent him from deleting the whole **buildings** node and only grant him full access to the **buildings/$pushKeys** he creates). Is that complicated? I may be getting this wrong, but doesn't firebase need to scan the **buildings** node before it *knows* which one belongs to the user?
>   If firebase rules can't resolve this issue like this, that means that in theory, every firebase app in which the user needs to read and write its own content to the realtime database, which is often the case, needs to store the information under a **users.uid** node to make it available to him/her. That seems to go against the "keep your database as flat as possible" firebase general instruction, and it also doesn't play well with the fact that any function with database references that have children in firebase require that data.snapshots nightmarish iteration. 
>   Moreover if you can't design a shallow structure, and the user id will constantly change, how would you go about writing the database references in the Apps firebase configuration:  *const buildingsRef = db.ref('users/'+ **userId!!!!**+'/buildings');* : >[How to constrain read/write rules to the users that create the nodes while keeping this structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679639/how-to-constrain-read-write-rules-to-the-users-that-create-the-nodes-while-keepi?noredirect=1#comment86387581_49679639)
>   There must be an **good way to do this without bending over backwards.**
>   ?

Comment: _"I know this is looking like a big mess"_ - I completely agree with this. Can you edit your question stating what you want (for example: users can read/write their own user node, every building, and only deps of buildings they own) and maybe reduce some of the explaining text. To much explaining/elaborating can actually make it harder to understand.

Comment: And for the first error about unsupported javascript: you have a . after the last child: `.child.('isAdmin')",` this should be `.child('isAdmin')",`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @André  . I have removed all my messy code and left only the question.

Comment: Can you put your last rules attempt back in your question? Something like "I tried this (rules) but i got these errors"

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen . done

Comment: First thing I noticed is `.child('$pushKey')`, which should be `.child('pushKey)` (without the quotes). It's not the cause of the error message, but it definitely means your rules don't work.

Comment: I've added an answer I think is correct but it's hard to tell because your datastructure is pretty complicated. So my suggestion would be to change the datastructure if you can. @FrankvanPuffelen Can you check it for possible errors or maybe improve it?

Comment: _"Does the user needs to be able read/write to both parent (buildings) and child node (buildings/$pushKey)?"_ This is a question you have to answer yourself.

Comment: @AndréKool  I don't see why it couldn't read/write to the **buildings** parent node (provided the rules prevent him from deleting the whole **buildings** node and only grant him full access to the **buildings/$pushKeys** he creates). Is that complicated? I may be getting this wrong, but doesn't firebase needs to scan the **buildings** node before he knows which one belongs to the user?

Comment: If firebase rules can't resolve this issue, that would mean that in theory, every firebase app in which the user needs to read and write its own content to the realtime database, which is often the case, needs to store the information under the **users.uid** node to make it available to him. That seems to go against the "keep your database as flat as possible" firebase general instruction, and it also doesn't play well with the fact that function with children queries in firebase require that data.snapshots _nightmarish_ iteration.

Comment: I think this is going in the wrong direction and getting overly complicated. I have the feeling we are focussing to much on the rules instead of what you want to do with your data.

Comment: All I want to do with my data is allow my users to create their own buildings and departments, to be able to access (read/write) their data and not other users' data.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the rules for each part of your datastructure:

For the users node I removed the more global read and write rules because if they are false they are redundant because that is the default state. And if they are true they will override these rules because [rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade). To allow users to only read/write their own data:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Next is the buildings node. Here you can read if you are the owner (ownerID === your uid) and write if [there is no data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data) or you are the owner:

```
"buildings" : {
    "$pushKey" : {
        ".read": "root.child('buildings').child($pushKey).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildings').child($pushKey).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

And last is the departments node where it gets a little tricky because a user can should only read/write departments in buildings he owns. So we have to check if the user has a building with the pushkey of the department. Here I check if the building with the value of inBuilding in the department has ownerID that is your uid (mind spinning complicated):

```
"depts" : {
    "$pushKey" : {
        ".read": "root.child('buildings').child(root.child('depts').child($pushKey).child('inBuilding').val()).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "root.child('buildings').child(root.child('depts').child($pushKey).child('inBuilding').val()).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Another option is changing your datastructure to something like this where you store buildings and departments under the user id:

```
{
    "buildings" : {
        "$uid" : {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
            "$buildingid" : {    
            }
        }
    },
    "depts" : {
        "$uid" : {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
            "$deptid" : {    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd solution I would have to constantly iterate through data.snapshots on all the app methods. The 1st solution, while it's  allowing me to write a new building it's not writing the **ownerId** node to the **buildings** (nor read anything at all for that matter).
it works if I add:
`buildings": {
".read": true,
      ".write": true,
       "$pushKey" : {
         ".read": "root.child('buildings').child($pushKey).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid",
         ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildings').child($pushKey).child('ownerID').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    },`

Comment: I could however write an **ownerID** node on the **depts** much like in the building node to ease the pain without any dificulty. I will update my question mentioning this.

Comment: The problem with the first solution is you are writing buildings in two steps, first the building and than you try to add the ownerid. The second step fails because there is already data present but their is no (or empty) ownerid. The second solution is more a general idea. Maybe a better way to explain it would be _"Think about how you can change your datastructure to fit your needs/use-cases."_

Comment: what if we lose the "!data.exists() " function?

Comment: I think it wouldnt be possible to write anything than, atleast not the way you are doing it now. In your case you have to check who owns the building. You cant check this if there is no buildingid. The solution is to include your ownerid in your first write that creates the building.

Comment: Ok I have managed to do that simply by changing the writing method to: 


`addBuilding: function () {
  let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  let buildingKey = buildingsRef.push().key;
 this.newBuilding.ownerID = userId;
  buildingsRef.child(buildingKey).set(this.newBuilding);
  usersRef.child(userId).child('isAdmin').child(buildingKey).set(true);
}`

and now it's writing the **ownerID** node. And while its showing the node on the frontend when I create it, if I refresh the node disappears from the screen... I will update the question again.