# How to import firebase reference from a method inside another component?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, components, vuefire

I am import a firebase at the top of my **/buildings.vue** component:

```
...
import buildingsadd, { buildingsRef } from './buildingsadd.vue';


export default {
  firebase() { 
    return { 
    buildings: buildingsRef
    }
  },
  components: {
    buildingsadd
  },
  name: 'buildings',
  ...
```

On the the **/buildingsadd.vue** component I am defining a new path to the the firebase ref like this:

```
...
import firebase from '../firebase-config';
import { db } from '../firebase-config';
export default {
  firebase() { 
    return {
    buildings:  buildingsRef,
    users: usersRef,
    }
  },
  name: 'buildingsadd',
  data () {
    return {
      newBuilding: {
        name: '',
      } 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addBuilding: function () {
      let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      let buildingsRef = db.ref('buildings/'+userId);
    }
...
```

But I am getting this errors:

[image] 
any ideas?

Answers to this would also solve my particular problem:

- [Is it possible to define a variable on the firebase database references path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676833/is-it-possible-to-define-a-variable-on-the-firebase-database-references-path/49678124?noredirect=1#comment86494792_49678124)

  [Vue.JS "for loop" is not displaying the items on firebase if I use the following firebase rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737932/vue-js-for-loop-is-not-displaying-the-items-on-firebase-if-i-use-the-following?noredirect=1#comment86490368_49737932)

  [Is it possible to bring the "user" object to the "top level" and access it from outside the "on.AuthSateChanged(user => .... }"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718494/is-it-possible-to-bring-the-user-object-to-the-top-level-and-access-it-from/49718650?noredirect=1#comment86450559_49718650)

  [How to constrain read/write rules to the users that create the nodes while keeping this structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679639/how-to-constrain-read-write-rules-to-the-users-that-create-the-nodes-while-keepi?noredirect=1#comment86387581_49679639)

Comment: Where is `db`, used in line `let buildingsRef = db.ref('buildings/'+userId);`  defined?

Comment: I didn't want to put all the code here to make it less confusing but I am defining it in the beginning of the script of the **buildingsadd.vue**. Just added it

Answer (score 0):

You are not exporting `buildingsRef`. Export it like below.

**buildingsadd.vue**:

```
import firebase from '../firebase-config';
import { db } from '../firebase-config';

let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;                  // added
export let buildingsRef = db.ref('buildings/'+userId);         // added

export default {
  // ... (all the same)
  methods: {
    addBuilding: function () {
                                                               // removed lines here
    }
...
```

Comment: I see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760478/how-to-get-the-user-info-to-the-data-part-of-the-app-in-vue-js you are importing `buildingsRef` from `'../firebase-config'`. So you ended up using this method, but in a different file, yes?