# Is it possible to define a variable on the firebase database references path?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I am trying to redefine all my apps database references so that I can write a specific set of of firebase rules (I need to add **buildings** and **depts** nodes inside the **user** node – read why: [What is the best practice to write the rules of Firebase in a situation like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654136/what-is-the-best-practice-to-write-the-rules-of-firebase-in-a-situation-like-thi?noredirect=1#comment86354831_49654136) ).

I am using a *firebase-config.js* and exporting all my app's database references to the app's components so  hopefully if I change this path I don't have to refactor the code on all the app's components.

I am trying to do it with a function (on my firebase-config.js file):

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import { store } from './store/store';


var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config)
export default !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
       let userRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.uid);
       let buildingsRef = userRef.child('buildings'); 
    }
})();
export const db = firebase.database(); 
export const usersRef = db.ref('users');
_// BUT THIS: "buildingsRef" is returning undefined!!! :(
export const buildingsRef = db.ref('users'+ "/" + buildingsRef) //buildingsRef is a variable
export const deptsRef = db.ref('depts');
```

The **buldingsRef** variable is returning undefined and it's writing the **buildings** to an **undefined** node.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3" : {
      "name" : "João Alves Marrucho",
      "userEmail" : "joaoalvesmarrucho@hotmail.com"
    },
    "undefined" : {
      "-L9M4lM7oZFfmJKorxjC" : {
        "address" : "",
        "name" : "b1",
        "ownerID" : "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I writing to the node with the following method (vue.js):

```
addBuilding: function () {
  let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  let buildingKey = buildingsRef.push().key
  this.newBuilding.ownerID = userId;
  buildingsRef.child(buildingKey).set(this.newBuilding);
}
```

Any thoughts on why the variable **buildingsRef** is returning undefined?

Here is my full *firebase-config.js* file: http://jsfiddle.net/UnXrw/85/

Comment: yesssssssssssss :-)

Comment: howwwwwwww :-)?

Comment: move those last 2 line (const db and let build) up above your .onAuth... function. Those 2 lines are precisely how you define a path/target to your db. ...What's not working?

Comment: It's saving the **building** to an **undefined** node (not the **user.uid** node)

`{
  "users" : {
    "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3" : {
      "name" : "João Alves Marrucho",
      "userEmail" : "joaoalvesmarrucho@gmail.com"
    },
    "undefined" : {
      "-L9M4lM7oZFfmJKorxjC" : {
        "address" : "",
        "name" : "b1",
        "ownerID" : "6hwNde08Wuaa9bfReR28niSbOsF3"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I have updated the question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you want something like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    let userRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.uid);
    let buildingsRef = userRef.child('buildings');
    // now do whatever you want with those refs
  }
});
```

Comment: Still returns "undefined". The 'export' may only appear at the top level and never inside the scope of a function. That would break the vue.js app.

Comment: I have added the link to a jsfiddle with my full firebase-config.js file to the question.

Comment: Is it possible to bring the "user" object to the "top level" and access it from outside the "on.AuthSateChanged(user => .... }" ?

Comment: Yes, but not until it's populated. `let user; firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(newUser => { user = newUser });`